# How to determine when ListView has child views?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapterview

I need to catch the moment when `ListView` has at least one child view to show hint, pointing the `listView.getChildAt(0)`. How do I catch this event?

Comment: try the getCount method in the list adapter

Answer (score 1):

as @Mikel said.. use `listView.getCount()` to determine whether the `ListView` has child views or not.

Comment: So, there is no corresponding events, I can only check if there are children by getChildCount()?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom adapter and as soon as an item has been added call a listener that you registered while creating the adapter.

Comment: AFAIK, the getView() is called when the child view is being prepared to attach, but is not attached to parent view yet.

Comment: I was more thinking about overriding the `add()` and `notifyDataSetChanged()` methods, but you're right, at that point they might not be visible yet.